# Can't add new VM to existing cloud service in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have create a new cloud service in Azure called "website" and now i'm trying to add multiple VMs in it via the Azure CLI client.  Here are the steps I've followed:

**1) Create the cloud service:**

```
azure service create --affinitygroup testazure myapptest
```

**2) Create the first web server without any issues:**

```
azure vm create --ssh 22 --virtual-network-name test3 --subnet-names "Subnet-1" --vm-size medium --custom-data startup-default --vm-name www01 myapptest "b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-13_10-amd64-server-20140507-en-us-30GB" "admin" [PASSWORD]
```

**3) Create the second web server:**

```
azure vm create --ssh 22 --virtual-network-name test3 --subnet-names "Subnet-1" --vm-size medium --custom-data startup-default --vm-name www02 myapptest "b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-13_10-amd64-server-20140507-en-us-30GB" "admin" [PASSWORD]
```

**Although I get the following error:**

```
error:   A VM with dns prefix "myapptest" already exists
error:   vm create command failed
```

I'm aware that the command format is as follows:

```
vm create [options] [dns-name] [image] [user-name] [password]
```

Essentially I'm trying to create multiple servers in the "**mytestapp**" cloud service, so I figured I would have to specify "mytestapp" for the "dns-name" parameter although apparently I'm wrong.  I can easily create this VM via the website within the "mytestapp" cloud service so I'm unsure why this doesn't work.

I would really appreciate any clarification on this matter.

Thanks!

Comment: I have not used CLI tools but I just looked up the help and found that there's a `-c` parameter which is used if you want the VM to connect to existing VM. Can you try creating the 2nd VM by adding this parameter?

Comment: I tried it and it solved my problem.  I didn't know exactly what that option was for but now I do.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Let me put this as an answer with some more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the CLI tools help (see screenshot), I see there's a `"-c"` parameter which should be used if you want the new Virtual Machine to connect to an existing Virtual Machine.

[image]

Since CLI tools are a wrapper over [`Azure Service Management API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx), if I am not mistaken `azure vm create` maps to [`Create Virtual Machine Deployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157194.aspx) operation but when you use `azure vm create -c`, it maps to [`Add Role`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157186.aspx) operation which is what you wanted to do.